# Django autoescape is not working in render_to_string(template)?

Tags: python, html, django, render-to-string

I am drafting an email template to users when they successfully updated their passwords.

I used {{ autoescape off }} in the template, which is rendered by using render_to_string().

However, the email content shows the HTML angle brackets directly like this:

> Hi <span style='color:blue'>user! </span>
>
> Your password is updated successfully!

---

I am using Django2.0 and my code looks like this:

**views.py**

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from django.template.loader import render_to_string

def sendmail(request, title)
    email_title = title
    email_content = render_to_string('template.html',{'username':request.user.username})
    recipient = request.user.email
    send_mail(
            email_title,
            email_content,
            'myemail@email.com',
            [recipient,],
            )
```

**template.html**

```
{{ autoescape off}}
Hi <span style='color:blue'>user! </span>
Your password is updated successfully!
{{ endautoescape }}
```

Is there anything wrong with my code?

Otherwise, is autoescape always on while using render_to_string()?

Comment: This can't have anything to do with auto escaping. That applies to HTML inserted into the template from a variable, which you're not doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with autoescape, which is for rendering variables (it is also a template tag, so you use it with `{% autoescape off %}`, not `{{ autoescape off }}`). It is doing nothing at all in your current template.

Your issue is that you're trying to put HTML into the plain text body of an email.

[`send_mail`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/email/#send-mail) expects a plain text message body. If you want to have a HTML body then you need to supply a `html_message` argument:

```
send_mail(
    email_title,
    '',  # Empty plain text body - not recommended and you should supply a plain text alternative
    'myemail@email.com',
    [recipient,],
    html_message=email_content,  # This will render as HTML
)
```

Comment: you are right! The send_mail() only expects plain text and that's why I couldn't add any styling. Also thank you for pointing out the template tag mistake. :P